# Google maps geocoding - reduce number of decimal place

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Although I like the accuracy of google maps, I was wondering how easy it is to modify their jquery code to limit the number of decimal places returned.

Here is the code I am working with: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Rr5PL/9/

How can it be achieved to have 5 decimal places returned on lat/long instead of ofthe 15 odd that it has at the moment?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Rr5PL/11/

```
$(latval).val(marker.getPosition().lat().toFixed(5));
$(longval).val(marker.getPosition().lng().toFixed(5));
```

Comment: Your example still prints out the full value im afraid

Comment: Have added it in one more place now, for the search result.  It worked perfectly for the case where you drag the marker.  http://jsfiddle.net/Rr5PL/17/